Wide bandwidth bioamplifier
I want to build an amplifier with a wide bandwidth.  It will be the bioamplifier for recording the so-called cochlear microphonics from bats and it will be used in research.  Usually the bioamplifiers have a very simple topology and I thought to implement it here too: the initial amplification by the instrumenattion amplifier, followed by the high pass filter with a corner frequency of about 50Hz, and then - by the low pass filter with a corner frequency of about 200 kHz (!).  The overall gain of the amplifier must be variable, about 1,000 to 10,000 or even 20,000.  I've built many bioamplifiers before, for the ECG, EMG, EEG recordings.  However, this cochlear microphonics amplifer is very special, because the required wide bandwidth.  Also, the CMRR should be very high even at high gain and at wide range of the frequencies.  I tried to use different instrumentation amplifiers and opamps and cannot achieve the above parameters, especially the wide bandwidth. So< I am looking for some suggestions of the choice of the components.  Any other tip/suggestion would be appreciated.
Below is the circuit of the cochlear amplifier for humans, published in some scientific journal (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1350453312001737?via%3Dihub).  However. humans do not hear sounds above 20 kHz, and, therefore, the amplifier for humans should not have such a wide bandwidth as in the case of bats.


200 kHz is not even warm for a video amplifier, of which many are available, and there are plenty of faster op-amps around like the max41x or even opa656. What's the level and output impedance for your sensor? What CM signal do you need to reject - level, impedance, frequency? A schematic of your input equivalent circuit would be useful.

What exactly is a bioamplifier?

An amplifier for biological signals - ECG, EMG, EKG, etc

The impedance of the metal electrodes used for cochler microphonics  is probably in the range of several kiloohm - a few megaohm.  The instrumentation amplfier with a high input impedance is sually used as an initial cascade.  The CM signals is mainly the line (50 Hz) interference.

"impedance of the metal electrodes used for cochler microphonics is probably in the range of several kiloohm - a few megaohm" - you should find this out exactly.

Well, it is hard to tell right now, but the paper that I cited above refers to the worst-case source impedance of 40 kOhms.

OPA656 seems promising. Is there a suitable instrumentation amplifier with a high input impedance and good gain-bandwidth product?

The simpler the better usually. Not much gain is needed when feeding a fast 24bit (or more) sigma/delta ADC. No analog filters really, no 50Hz filter - all this is done digitally afterwards. The ADC has way more dynamic range than there's signal so it will capture artifacts without saturation and allow you to recover more signal than a higher gain signal chain.

AD8224 may not be the best part for it though. At G=10 (the highest you can use for 200kHz-ish bandwidth) it has CMRR=80dB, whereas at G=100 is reaches its full potential of CMRR=100dB (100kHz). You'll need a faster amplifier probably, or a carefully designed symmetric stage that applies G=10..25x to each input single-ended. A synchronous-sampling 2-channel ADC (TI has some cool parts like that, 2..6 channels) will do a good job at capture. You can then use an adaptive digital filter to get good CMRR. You will find much lower noise op-amps than in-amps, so noise vs. CMRR tradeoff can be made.

To evaluate this you'll need to do some guesstimating of the impedance range the electrodes may offer when attached to a bat. Then make a board that's a phantom: it has resistors and capacitors that mimic impedance between each pair of electrodes. The phantom should take a signal generator output and scale it down to amplitude expected from the biosignal. Then you can evaluate various approaches and decide what will work best. Then real measurements on bats may force you to reevaluate how good the phantom was :) AC couple the chain so it can attenuate 50/60Hz naturally.
